# uibutton font subclass

Tags: cocoa, uibutton

I have the following method in my UIButton class:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:16];
    self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

}
return self;
}
```

Works great except I can't see the border around the button: any ideas why?  What do I have to do extra to make the button border show?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not subclass button do everything in IB it would be more better. This is how You can achieve what you want:

Select **button** -> go to **Attributes Inspector** -> **Type** -> select **Rounded Rect**. That will give You default button look.

Then select **font** (Press on **T** Letter) like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Also select text color behind Font.

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot 2]

**EDIT:**

**Create button programmatically:**

```
//create the button with RoundedRect type
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

//set the position of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 100, 30);

//set the button's title
[button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set the button's font
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:16];

//set the button's line break mode
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

//set the button's text color
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // don't use this because button's text color after clicking it will be blue (default).

//add the button to the view
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot 3]

**Note:** Do not use `textColor` because Your text color after clicking the button will be default blue.

Comment: Hey Justin, your tutorials are great! It's just I use so many buttons of this style, it'd be quicker to change the class instead of keep changing the attributes every time. Do you know the final step I need to achieve this?

Comment: @RobW Yes, change class would be more quicker but duplicate created button it would be quick enough also. So You can do that. And about programatically: as far as I know button's type can't be changed when it was created (and You need to change to `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`) so if You want to achieve this programatically - **create all button programmatically in code** without using IB.

Comment: @RobW take a look at the updated answer. I added code how to create button programmatically and commented it.